# Why RestController doesn't work in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot Starter with a REST Controller working perfect:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping("/") 
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello world"; 
    }

}
```

However, when I add other Controller with infinite loop the REST Controller doesn't work:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
```

It is a samle code of other Controller.

```
@Component 
public class HelloWorld {

    @Autowired
    public void hello() 
    {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
            Thread.sleep(12000);
        } 
    }
}
```

So, other Controller (HelloWorld class) is always working, while RestController (SimpleController class) works only if other Controller is disabled.
**Why so?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your application never start properly. While Spring try to create the bean instances, set up dependencies and the whole infrastucrures, it start an infinite loop. It stuck on that, so your server never finish to starts, application context never setup. Note that the startup (mostly) runs on the main thread, and you block it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, I could see in the logs that Application has not completed the initialization stage. So have I create a parralel thread for the loop to fix the issue?

Comment: it depends, what do you want to achive?

Comment: I just want that both of this controllers working simuletiously.

Comment: if you want to test this behaviour, then yes, you can start it on other thread.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, you can use an implementation of `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` like

```
package com.example.restservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CommandRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!" +  helloWorld);
            Thread.sleep(12000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you use a `@Scheduled` method so you don't have an infinite loop code smell?

Comment: yeah. That is better option for your usecase

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Thank you very much for your excellent explanation and code example. I appreciate you have shared your knowledge!

Comment: In real world, scheduled jobs are the best way to achieve 'infinite loops'. For sandboxes, you can use worker thread etc...